# How would I load an ogg file in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

My goal is to load ogg files in node.js
I've tried ReadFile but hits me up with this error: Could not read file. [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Main\game\songs\test\Voices.ogg'] and the file does exist.

Code:

```
fs.readdir('./game/songs', function(err, files){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Could not list the directory.", err)
            return
        }
        files.forEach(function(file, index){
            fs.readFile('./game/songs/'+file+"/Inst.ogg", function(err, data){
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Could not read file.", err)
                    return
                }
            })
            fs.readFile('./game/songs/'+file+"/Voices.ogg", function(err, data){
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Could not read file.", err)
                    return
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the absolute path of the file, use the built-in `path` module's `join()` function:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'YOUR_PATH_HERE'), function(err, data) {});
```